# Matching a word with pound (#) symbol in a regex

Tags: java, android, regex, text

I have regexp for check if some text containing word (with ignoring boundary)
`String regexp = ".*\\bSOME_WORD_HERE\\b.*";`
but this regexp return `false` when "SOME_WORD" starts with # (hashtag).

```
Example, without #   
String text = "some text and test word";
String matchingWord = "test";
boolean contains = text.matches(".*\\b" + matchingWord + "\\b.*");
// now contains == true; 

But with hashtag `contains` was false. Example:
text = "some text and #test word";
matchingWord = "#test"; 
contains = text.matches(".*\\b" + matchingWord + "\\b.*");
//contains == fasle; but I expect true
```

Comment: So, what do you need to match as a word boundary? Start of string or whitespace? Usually, you can use `(?<!\\S)` as the initial boundary and `(?!\\S)` as the trailing one in such cases (`text.matches(".*(?<!\\S)" + matchingWord + "(?!\\S).*");`).

Comment: Another usual solution to make sure the search word is not inside word chars is using unambiguous word boundaries: `text.matches(".*(?<!\\w)" + matchingWord + "(?!\\w).*")`

Comment: you can simply use `text.contains("#test")` result will be `true` , if you have some special cases or multiple scenarios then go for `regex`

Comment: @PavneetSingh: That will also return `true` if there is `#testing` in the text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah thats true, i was going to advice OP some advice in previous comment

Comment: I posted an answer below, please check and let know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\b#` pattern matches a `#` that is preceded with a word character: a letter, digit or underscore.

If you need to match `#` that is not preceded with a word char, use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\w)`. Similarly, to make sure the trailing `\b` matches if a non-word char is there, use `(?!\w)` negative lookahead:

```
text.matches("(?s).*(?<!\\w)" + matchingWord + "(?!\\w).*");
```

Using `Pattern.quote(matchingWord)` is a good idea if your `matchingWord` can contain special regex metacharacters.

Alternatively, if you plan to match your search words in between whitespace or start/end of string, you can use `(?<!\S)` as the initial boundary and `(?!\S)` as the trailing one

```
text.matches("(?s).*(?<!\\S)" + matchingWord + "(?!\\S).*");
```

And one more thing: the `.*` in the `.matches` is not the best regex solution. A regex like `"(?<!\\S)" + matchingWord + "(?!\\S)"` with `Matcher#find()` will be processed in a much more optimized way, but you will need to initialize the `Matcher` object for that.

Comment: This work, thank you. But one thing. If after matching word in text I have new line symbol then matcher return false. Examlple `"test #test\ntest"`.  Can you please impove this regexp?

Comment: Add `(?s)`. But if you use `Matcher#find()`, you would not even need that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for words with leading '#', just simple remove the leading '#' from the searchword and use following regex.

```
text.matches("#\\b" + matchingWordWithoutLeadingHash + "\\b");
```