# How to parse a string in the URI that contains hash sign

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having trouble with parsing a string that contains "#" in URI, I want to open Device Dial-Up and parse this string "*344*12*#" to it.
the below code is my implementation and the problem is that I get the string without "#" in Dial-Up.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerAdapterDataView holder, int i) {

    final String code = list.get(i).getActivation();
    holder.activation.setText("Activation Code:  "+code);

    holder.activate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (code.contains("#")){
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+code));
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396917/matching-a-word-with-pound-symbol-in-a-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code this may help

```
        if (code.contains("#")){
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(code))); //here add Uri.encode
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
```